# String comparison in if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have the following Bash script, but I get an error in the predicate of my if statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash 
$UQ = "noqueue:" 
read -p "Address: " email
id=$(grep $email  mx.log | grep status | awk '{print  $6 }') 
read b <<<$id
read a <<<$email 

if (($id == $UQ )); 
then 
    grep $email mx.log
else 
    for((i=0;i<${#a[@]};i++)); do
        for ((j=0;j<${#b[@]};j++))
        do
           c+=(${a[i]}:${b[j]});
        done 
    done
    for i in ${c[@]}; do
       echo $i 
    done 
fi
```

Comment: `$UQ = "noqueue:"` is not how you do shell assignment. You mean `UQ="noqueue:"`. No `$` on assignment and no spaces around `=`.

Comment: You also want to `"quote"` variables when you use them. So `grep "$email"`, `<<<"$email"`, etc. Also what is `a<<<"$email"` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `read a <<< $email` assigns the value of `$email`, minus leading and trailing whitespace, to `a`. Unless that's what you intended, `a=$email` is much more straightforward.

Comment: In short words, i try to build a logparser for 4 different server logs, and  the id is changes every server exchange - so i thought maby array where is data like email:id:newID would be easy to parse these logs.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you specified precisely what error you got, but I'm pretty sure that it is because `$id` is not a number. The `((...))` compound command performs **arithmetic** evaluation, and shell variables expanded in such a construction must expand to arithmetic expressions.

For string comparison, use the `[[ ... ]]` compound command (and don't forget to put spaces around the double brackets). That expects a conditional expression, where `==` is string equality (and `-eq` is available for numerical equality).

Comment: @MartinTee: As I said, **don't forget to put spaces around the double brackets**.

Comment: @MartinTee Didn't you see Etan Reisner's comment on the issue of setting UQ?